# Retrieve the coding amino-acid when there is certain pattern in a DNA sequence

Tags: regex, perl, bioinformatics, biopython, bioperl

I would like to retrieve the coding amino-acid when there is certain pattern in a DNA sequence. For example, the pattern could be: ATAGTA. So, when having:

Input file:

```
>sequence1
ATGGCGCATAGTAATGC
>sequence2
ATGATAGTAATGCGCGC
```

The ideal output would be a table having for each amino-acid the number of times is coded by the pattern. Here in sequence1, pattern codes only for one amino-acid, but in sequence2 it codes for two. I would like to have this tool working to scale to thousands of sequences. I've been thinking about how to get this done, but I only thought to: replace all nucleotides different than the pattern, translate what remains and get summary of the coded amino-acids.

Please let me know if this task can be performed by an already available tool.

Thanks for your help. All the best, Bernardo

---

Edit (due to the confusion generated with my post):

Please forget the original post and sequence1 and sequence2 too.

Hi all, and sorry for the confusion. The input fasta file is a *.ffn file derived from a GenBank file using 'FeatureExtract' tool (http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/services/FeatureExtract/download.php), so a can imagine they are already in frame (+1) and there is no need to get amino-acids coded in a frame different than +1.

I would like to know for which amino-acid the following sequences are coding for:

```
AGAGAG
GAGAGA
CTCTCT
TCTCTC
```

The unique strings I want to get coding amino-acids are repeats of three AG, GA, CT or TC, that is (AG)3, (GA)3, (CT)3 and (TC)3, respectively. I don't want the program to retrieve coding amino-acids for repeats of four or more.

Thanks again, Bernardo

Comment: Pattern `ATAGTA` doe not show up in any of the sequence?

Comment: @Jotne: It does: `ATGGCGC<ATAGTA>ATGC`, `ATG<ATAGTA>ATGCGCGC`. I do not understand what "codes for two" means, though.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, need some coffee :)

Comment: Do you only want it in the single reading frame or do you have to allow for all three?

Comment: BioPerl will probably be of use to you: http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: What does 'codes for two mean'? I only see one instance of ATAGTA in sequence 2.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Anyone else notice that almost every question posted on this site about DNA has a ton of information about DNA and almost no information that would help us figure out what the poster wants to do with their text file? @popnard - just post the sample input, expected output and tell us what you need to do in terms of the patterns of strings in your files, drop all the DNA terminology as it just obfuscates your question.

Comment: The post has been edited, maybe now is more clear. Thanks again to all!

Comment: Can you confirm that the input file is like [Wikipedia's def for FASTA format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) and post a few entries of data in the question?  Along with that data please specify what you mean by frames.  Are repeats excepted to be: by line or multiple lines etc?  Better still, follow EdMorton's advice and describe the input file format, the test data and what you want as an output.  Please read [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/) - you're question is lacking "Self Contained".

Comment: @EdMorton That's bioinformaticians for you -- they're generally red hot on the biology part, and generally not so much on the programming side. This manifests as a varying, but generally profound, inability to formulate an algorithm; they almost always know *what* they want to derive from what they have, but rarely have the slightest inkling of *how*. This is why those with strong CS backgrounds tend to stand out so strongly by comparison, and also why the field's worth considering even for programmers with no significant background in biology; they need us quite badly, and largely know it.

Comment: From above: `sorry for the confusion` immediately followed by `The input fasta file is a *.ffn file derived from a GenBank file using 'FeatureExtract' tool (http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/services/FeatureExtract/download.php), so a can imagine they are already in frame (+1) and there is no need to get amino-acids coded in a frame different than +1.`. Absolutely hilarious - I'm still smiling (and no nearer a clue to what the question is but I don't care any more, that was great)!

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that should at least get you started. For example, you can run like:

```
./retrieve_coding_aa.pl file.fa ATAGTA
```

Contents of `retrieve_coding_aa.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;
use Bio::SeqIO;
use Bio::Tools::CodonTable;
use Data::Dumper;

my $pattern = $ARGV[1];

my $fasta = Bio::SeqIO->new ( -file => $ARGV[0], -format => 'fasta');

while (my $seq = $fasta->next_seq ) {

    my $pos = 0;

    my %counts;

    for (split /($pattern)/ => $seq->seq) {

        if ($_ eq $pattern) {

            my $dist = $pos % 3;

            unless ($dist == 0) {

                my $num = 3 - $dist;

                s/.{$num}//;

                chop until length () % 3 == 0;
            }

            my $table = Bio::Tools::CodonTable->new();

            $counts{$_}++ for split (//, $table->translate($_));
        }

        $pos += length;
    }

    print $seq->display_id() . ":\n";

    map {

        print "$_ => $counts{$_}\n"
    }
    sort {

        $counts{$a} <=> $counts{$b}
    }
    keys %counts;

    print "\n";
}
```

Here are the results using the sample input:

```
sequence1:
S => 1

sequence2:
V => 1
I => 1
```

---

The `Bio::Tools::CodonTable` class also supports non-standard codon usage tables. You can change the table using the `id` pointer. For example:

```
$table = Bio::Tools::CodonTable->new( -id => 5 );
```

or:

```
$table->id(5);
```

For more information, including how to examine these tables, please see the documentation here: [http://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::Tools::CodonTable](http://metacpan.org/pod/Bio%3a%3aTools%3a%3aCodonTable)

Answer (score 0):

I will stick to that first version of what you wanted cause the addendum only confused me even more. (frame?)
I only found ATAGTA once in sequence2 but I assume you want the mirror images/reverse sequence as well, which would be ATGATA in this case. Well my script doesn't do that so you would have to write it up twice in the input_sequences file but that should be no problem I would think.

I work with a file like yours which I call "dna.txt" and a input sequences file called "input_seq.txt". The result file is a listing of patterns and their occurences in the dna.txt file (including overlap-results but it can be set to non-overlap as explained in the awk).

input_seq.txt:

```
GC
ATA
ATAGTA
ATGATA
```

dna.txt:

```
>sequence1
ATGGCGCATAGTAATGC
>sequence2
ATGATAGTAATGCGCGC
```

results.txt:

```
GC,6
ATA,2
ATAGTA,2
ATGATA,1
```

Code is awk calling another awk (but one of them is simple). You have to run
 "./match_patterns.awk input_seq.txt" to get the results file generated.:

*match_patterns.awk:*

```
#! /bin/awk -f
{return_value= system("awk -vsubval="$1" -f test.awk dna.txt")}
```

*test.awk:*

```
#! /bin/awk -f
{string=$0
do
{
where = match(string, subval)
# code is for overlapping matches (i.e ATA matches twice in ATATAC)
# for non-overlapping replace +1 by +RLENGTH in following line
if (RSTART!=0){count++; string=substr(string,RSTART+1)}
}
while (RSTART != 0)
}
END{print subval","count >> "results.txt"}
```

Files have to be all in the same directory.

Good luck!

Comment: Answering this question would be difficult without some knowledge of molecular biology. Amino acids are coded for in triplets of nucleotides called codons. There are therefore six possible reading frames; three in the forward direction and three in the reverse. The OP is probably only interested in the first frame (i.e. +1), probably because his sample sequences are the beginnings of some genes or ORFs of interest. In these sequences, the first codon, 'ATG', is a common eukaryotic start codon, which, after transcription, would signal the initiation of protein translation.

Comment: Using `awk` for this job is not an appropriate tool; unless of course you wish to re-invent the wheel. The years of work put into the BioPerl and BioPython modules need not be wasted. They're there to help.

Comment: Maybe you are right if Bernardo wants to write a new class for Bioperl. But it's perl isn't it? Just writing up adhoc solutions that is. So one might as well just want to use awk and look for whatever number of sequences in one go. I have no clue about molecular biology but as I see it, it is just looking for patterns in a file.

Comment: Yes, really only a small amount of perl is needed to get to the answer the OP is looking for. I would avoid `awk` because eventually the OP will want to convert codons to amino-acids; which would require a look-up table, and I wouldn't want to write one of those up, ever. The OP is looking for patterns, but he's only interested in the parts of those patterns that are _in frame_. I believe the OP then wants these translated _in silico_ with their counts. Perl (and Python) has modules that can do this.